# How to create and alter two different table in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `user_info`. Now I am taking a input from user (eg. abc). I want to create a table with name `abc` and add column `abc` in `user_info` table. I searched on google and find `union` but I don't think so `union` will help me out.

Comment: NO, don't create table names from data. That is bad DB design.

Comment: Its a requirement of my project. I'll handle all things. It will not effect on my db.

Comment: You need to rethink your project then, because this is a very horrible idea for DB design.  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: ok! I'll rethink about it. But is this possible to create and alter table in single query

Comment: No, it's not.  And it doesn't make any logical sense to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like this:

```
declare @tblName varchar(50) = 'abc'
declare @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'Create Table ' + @tblName + ' (col1 varchar(50))'
EXEC(@SQL)

SET @SQL = 'Alter Table user_info ADD ' + @tblName + ' varchar(50)'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

This will create a table named `abc`, with a column named `col1` and datatype `varchar(50)`. Then add a column to the `user_info` table with the name `abc` and a datatype of `varchar(50)`

If you want it both in one single line, you could just join the strings together instead of executing them separatly:

```
SET @SQL = 'Create Table ' + @tblName + ' (col1 varchar(50))' +
    ' Alter Table user_info ADD ' + @tblName + ' varchar(50)'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

You could add as many statements as you want really to that string, just concatenate it all together.

Comment: You are using two queries. I mentioned clearly that I want single query.